# ClickHouse Distributed tables and insert_quorum

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to configure a cluster with both sharding and replication and have some doubts about how insert_quorum works with Distributed engine and internal replication.

insert_quorum controls synchronous insertion to multiple instances of Replicated* tables (if insert_quorum>=2 the client will return only after data was successfully inserted in insert_quorum replicas).

insert_distributed_sync controls synchronous insertion to Distributed table. if insert_distributed_sync=1 client will return only after data was successfully inserted in target tables (one replica if internal_replication is true).

But how do insert_distributed_sync, insert_quorum and internal_replication work together?
Is my understanding correct that if I execute insert into Distributed table with insert_distributed_sync=1 and insert_quorum=2 the statement will return only after the data was inserted in at least two replicas?
Or is insert_quorum ignored for Distributed engine and works only when writing directly with Replicated* tables?

Answer (score 2):

As I understood

- `internal_replication` and `insert_distributed_sync` apply to Distributed engine
- `insert_quorum` applied to ReplicatedMergeTree

`INSERT` query to `Distributed` table which created over multiple `*ReplicatedMergeTree` with `insert_distributed_sync=1`, will invoke multiple inserts into ReplicatedMergeTree tables inside the initial clickhouse-server process use authentication from `remote_servers` config part.

It will one Insert for each Shard according to sharding key which you defined when create `Distributed` table.

If you define internal_replication=true, then only One *ReplicatedMergeTree table should be written, but when Distributed engine insert into ReplicatedMergeTree, initial clickhouse-server serves query as a client, so `insert_quorum` should apply on destination `clickhouse-server` and initial server will get an answer only after all inserted parts will replicate over ZK.

If you define internal_replication=false, then the `Distributed` engine should initiate insert to all *ReplicatedMergeTree, and `insert_quorum` also will apply, but replication conflicts should be resolved on over Zookeeper Queues on `ReplicatedMergeTree` side, cause inserted parts will have the same control sums and names.